# Misuse of shell builtins when adding an ssh key using ssh-add

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, ssh-keys

I have a `script.sh` file which checks for loaded SSH agent and adds a key.

If I run this script directly, it works but if I run it via some worker it doesn't unless I do those changes:

This works:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -e

printf "<<<<< Start SSH agent and Github deploy key >>>>>\n"
if ps -p $SSH_AGENT_PID > /dev/null
then
  printf "<<<<< ssh-agent is already running >>>>>\n"
else
  eval `ssh-agent -s`
fi
ssh-add $deploy_key_path
```

But his doesn't work:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -e

if [ $(ps ax | grep [s]sh-agent | wc -l) -gt 0 ] ; then
  printf "<<<<< ssh-agent is already running >>>>>\n"
else
  eval `ssh-agent -s`
fi
ssh-add $deploy_key_path
```

The error says `...failed.  Exit Code: 2(Misuse of shell builtins)..` which happens at the line `ssh-add $deploy_key_path`

When checking the [reserved Bash error codes](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/196563) I see:

```
2   Misuse of shell builtins    empty_function() {} Missing keyword or command
```

Comment: I don't see how you could get the error on that line. I think it could only happen on the `eval` line.

Comment: Replace `eval` with `echo` to see what it's trying to evaluate.

Comment: I'd recommend running your script through https://shellcheck.net

Comment: BTW, `grep ... | wc -l` can be combined into `grep -c ...`

Comment: Where do you set `deploy_key_path`? If it's set by `eval`, then the line that uses it should be in the `else`.

Comment: You should put `[s]sh-agent` in quotes. Or use `pgrep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one reasonable way I'd use `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`, minimizing security risks by not keeping keys unlocked more than it is strictly needed within the script.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Do not leave key unlocked after execution of this script
trap 'ssh-add -d "$deploy_key_path"' EXIT INT

# If ssh-agent has an auth socket or has a PID
if [ -S "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || ps -p "$SSH_AGENT_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  printf '<<<<< ssh-agent is already running >>>>>\n'
else
  # Do not use back-ticks as it is legacy obsolete
  eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
fi

# Do not leave key unlocked more than 5 minutes
ssh-add -t 600 "$deploy_key_path"
```